# Remove lettering for references with same first author, different second author, and same year

Tags: natbib, author-number

I have 2 references with same first author but different other authors and same year (2006).  Currently, these entries are appearing as 2006a and 2006b in my bibliography and in-text citations.  I want them to appear as simply 2006 (no a or b).  In the text, I will always use \citet* to refer to these articles, therefore there should be no confusion in the text.  A MWE for the tex file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{./bibliostyle}
\begin{document}
Article 1: \citet*{angchenxing2006rfs}.
Article 2: \citet*{anghodrickxingzhang2006jf}.
\bibliography{./BibTest}
\end{document}
```

My .bib file is:

```
@article{angchenxing2006rfs,
author = {Ang, Andrew and Chen, Joseph and Yuhang Xing},
title = {Downside Risk},
journal = {Review of Financial Studies},
volume = {19},
number = {4},
pages = {1191-1239},
year = {2006}
}

@article{anghodrickxingzhang2006jf,
author = {Ang, Andrew and Hodrick, Robert J. and Xing, Yuhang and Zhang, Xiaoyan},
title = {The Cross-Section of Volatility and Expected Returns},
journal = {Journal of Finance},
year = {2006},
volume = {61},
number = {1}
pages = {259-299}
}
```

My .sty file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1LaWwesHOKWdGd5U0lnaFcwTDA/edit?usp=sharing).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could your objective be summarized as saying that you do not want to perform truncation of the author list in all citation callouts? Or does the non-truncation of the list of authors apply only to bib entries where the first author in the list is shared across the entries -- as in the two Ang et al examples you've given? (For consistency of appearance, I think you should probably do no truncation at all.)

Comment: Thank you Mico for responding.  In most cases I will truncate the author list (i.e. Ang et al. (2006)).  It is only the case where the first author and year are the same, but other authors are different, that I do not want to truncate.  If all authors are the same and year is the same, then I will truncate and use the standard a, b, c convention.  It is only when first author is same, year is same, and other authors are different that I need to deviate from the standard practice.  Unfortunately these are the instructions I've received.

Answer (score 3):

The usual workaround is to add something that will not show in print.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{angchenxing2006rfs,
author = {Ang, Andrew and Chen, Joseph and Yuhang Xing},
title = {Downside Risk},
journal = {Review of Financial Studies},
volume = {19},
number = {4},
pages = {1191-1239},
year = {\NOOP{2006.1}2006}
}

@article{anghodrickxingzhang2006jf,
author = {Ang, Andrew and Hodrick, Robert J. and Xing, Yuhang and Zhang, Xiaoyan},
title = {The Cross-Section of Volatility and Expected Returns},
journal = {Journal of Finance},
year = {\NOOP{2006.2}2006},
volume = {61},
number = {1},
pages = {259-299}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\providecommand{\NOOP}[1]{}

\begin{document}
Article 1: \citet*{angchenxing2006rfs}.
Article 2: \citet*{anghodrickxingzhang2006jf}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I don't have your `.bst` style, but there should be no problem in using this trick also with it.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought of the old, versatile `\noop` trick! Here's a really brilliant application of this macro!!